# iTunes connect : Your file could not be loaded. Try again

Tags: app-store-connect

I am trying to upload my app on to iTunes, but while uploading the app icon and the screen shots, got an error as:

> "Your file could not be loaded. Try again".

[image]

Please help me if anyone knows the solution.

Comment: It seems like you are using Google Chrome. Did you try using Google Chrome Incognito mode?

Comment: Similar issue happened to me on screenshot part. After refreshed the page issue got resolved. I have tried this in `Google chrome 73.0.3683.103` and `macOS Mojave 10.14.4`

Answer (score 37):

*This appears to be browser related. Below are a list of browsers that users have claimed allow uploads as well as those that show the error.*

#### Uploads Function Properly

- Safari Version 10.1.1 (12603.2.4)
- Chrome (Version 79.0.3945.88)

#### Uploads Error Out

- Chrome (Version 59.0.3071.115)
- Firefox Developers Edition (60.0b2)
- Safari (13.0)
- Safari Technology Preview (Release 97 (Safari 13.1, WebKit 15609.1.11.4))

Comment: This one. This is the one, guys.

Comment: Wow - spot on. The same assets uploaded error-free in Safari. Thanks @qix.

Comment: Yup, works in Safari. Was failing for me in Firefox Developers Edition 60.0b2 (64-bit)

Comment: Confirm it works on Safari, does not work on Firefox.  Yet another hour wasted on things like this.

Comment: This is the correct answer!

Comment: I've got this error using Safari 13.0

Comment: @Muganwas I did too. I think this answer should be broadened to state that you should just try different browsers. Not sure it will age well otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

**My network was blocking me from accessing some Apple servers.**

Fixed the issue by using VPN or changing the network.

Answer (score 0):

**You have to put your app icon in this box of size 1024x1024. And your icon should not be transparent.**

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your app icon does not contain alpha.

File >> Export >> Unmark alpha tick if marked.

please check attachement

[image]